# Keycloak Admin REST-API Synchronize federation mapper

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am using Keycloak 9.0.3 with a LDAP-user federation, with edit mode = WRITABLE and Import Users = on.
I am developing a spring boot application that should call the Keycloak REST API to create, update, delete **users** and **groups** in LDAP.  I also created "group-ldap-mapper" in my user federation to map LDAP-Groups to Keycloak-Groups and vise-versa.

My requirement is to create and delete Keycloak-groups via the REST API and they get mapped to groups in LDAP using the mapper above. When my application calls **POST /{realm}/groups** Keycloak just creates the group in Keycloak-DB and does not synchronise to LDAP unless the group gets assigned to some user. This is actually not a big problem.
The real problem is when my application deletes the group via **DELETE /{realm}/groups/{id}**. The groups gets deleted from the Keycloak-DB but not from LDAP. 
An acceptable workaround would be to call **POST /{realm}/user-storage/{parentId}/mappers/{id}/sync** which synchronises the Groups and does the job.

The problem in this workaround, that there is no way to get the federation mapper id ({id}) other than hardcoding it in the spring application. There is no REST-Call to retrieve this id programatically.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I found the following Red Hat issues about LDAP-Groups synchronisation https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-13716 and https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-13963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to find the ids of the federation and the group-ldap-mapper programatically to use them in the call POST /{realm}/user-storage/{parentId}/mappers/{id}/sync.

One can call GET /{realm}/components. This returns among other things federation and mappers. In my case I could find the federation id from the UserRepresentation and then I used it to filter the components (parent={federation id}). According to documentation there is also a type Query, but I could not figure out the right value.